# Count matches between specific substrings

Tags: perl, substring

I have a string

```
1AAAAaaa>###_1BBbbbbbbb>###_2CCCCCCCCccccc
```

Data blocks begins with "a number" and end with `>`.

I need to calculate in how many of those blocks lower case letters outnumber upper case.

As an answer I want to get

```
there are x places between number and >, where lowercase is over 50%.
```

I understand how to do it for the whole string, but not for the separate regions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you already have code to do this for your whole string, that's good. Please [edit] your question and include that. We are much more inclined to help with a concrete problem than with what reads mostly like a list of requirements. Please also explain in more detail what you mean by _over 50%_. Is that the number of characters that are lower-case, in relation to all characters?

Comment: As a general suggestion, it sounds like you might want to do this with a regular expression. You don't always have to do everything in a complicated regex. I'd probably split the string up into regions, and process each one completely individually. If you do that, your solution for the whole string should just work.

Comment: Split the problem into steps that you can solve using `my @blocks = $string =~ /.*>/g` You know the rest from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate each target section of the string into an array using split.
Then iterate through the array and do your count.

```
my $string = 'AAAAaaa>1BBbbbbbbb>2CCCCCCCCccccc>3DDDDDDDDDddd>4FFFFfffffff>';

my @targets = split(/(?=\d+\w+>)/, $string);
my $successes = 0;

foreach my $target (@targets){
    my $target_lc = $target =~ tr/a-z//;
    my $target_uc = $target =~ tr/A-Z//;

    if($target_lc > $target_uc){
        $successes++;
    }
}

print $successes;
```

OUTPUT = 2

Comment: While this is an approximation to an answer, there are number of issues. The OP says that *"Data blocks begins with "a number" and end with >"* yet your data blocks begin with a `>` and numbers are ignored. This unnecessarily perverts the concept and provides no advantages. Your `@targets` array contains a superfluous final element with the value `>` which obviously contains no letters of either case. Also, it is unconventional to use `s///` replacing characters with themselves to count characters in a string: the canonical way is to use `tr///`, as in `$target_lc = $target =~ tr/a-z//` etc.

Comment: Borodin is absolutely right. I have edited the solution to be more correct.

Comment: Your update is incorrect. `tr///` does not use regular expressions, so square brackets `[` and `]` will be counted as well.

Comment: There is no need for an elaborate `split` call when a simple global capture will do fine: `my @targets = $string =~ /\d.*?>/g`. You also know nothing about the contents of the substrings between the number and the `>`, so it is wrong to assume that it will match `\w+`. Either `.*?` or `[^>]*`would be fine.